# Confusion on the relationship between laplace distribution and exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

If $X \sim Laplace(\mu, b)$ and $\mu = 0$ such that $X \sim Laplace(0,b)$, it becomes a form of the exponential family. Unfortunately, one source tells me that it becomes $|X| \sim exponential(b)$, another source says that $X \sim exponential(\frac{1}{b})$, and my notes say that $X \sim exponential(b)$.

Can any of y'all help me out on this?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that there are two common ways to parameterize exponential distributions (... and the same issue occurs for [gamma distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) more generally).

One is the *rate form* of the exponential,

$f_X(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}; \theta>0, x>0$

the other is the *scale form*

$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\mu} e^{-x/\mu}; \mu>0, x>0$

with $\mu = 1/\theta$, these two forms are equivalent.

Usually you can guess which form is being used from context.

For example, for the exponential, Wikipedia [first gives the rate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Characterization) (with rate $\lambda$):

$$f(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}, & x \ge 0, \\0, & x < 0.\end{cases}$$

and [then gives the scale form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Alternative_parameterization) (with scale $\beta$):

$$f(x;\beta) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\beta} e^{-x/\beta}, & x \ge 0, \\0, & x < 0.\end{cases}$$

Correspondingly, you can write the Laplace distribution *either way*.

For the Laplace distribution, Wikipedia gives the [scale form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) - which is the more common parameterization in the case of the Laplace - but the rate form is equally valid.